# PHP: update on DB if i pass it through get url

Tags: php, mysql

I have a link as example: 
http://www.example.com/InvoiceUpdate/InvoiceUpdate.php?invoiceNo=1&OrderNo=1&InvoiceStatus=1

I would like to write a code in php to change on DB through GET URL.
Change as example: InvoiceStatus for every InvoiceNo and OrderNo in Table called Orders.

Note I am working in this page: InvoiceUpdate.php

Comment: could you provide your php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to get the values of the parameters in the GET Request. You can do it like the following.

```
$invoiceNo = $_REQUEST['invoiceNo'];
$OrderNo = $_REQUEST['OrderNo'];
$invoiceStatus = $_REQUEST['invoiceStatus'];
```

Then you can update your database table with an update query in the following fashion.

```
$connection = new mysqli("your_server", "username", "password", "dbname");

$sql = "Update Orders Set orderNo = $OrderNo, invoiceStatus = $invoiceStatus where invoiceNo = $invoiceNo";

$connection->query($sql);
```

Comment: @AhedAli Please upvote this answer and mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your InvoiceUpdate.php just use your global $_GET params 
`$_GET['invoiceNo']` and use like a variable or like u want :)

```
`UPDATE `yourtable`   
SET `invoiceNo` = :invoiceNo,
WHERE `invoiceNo` = :invoiceNo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['invoiceNo']) and !empty($_GET['invoiceNo'])) {
        // Your update query here
    }
?>
```

Comment: this is another way for the solution! Thanks